# Can I make an Off-Canvas Slideout Menu in CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make an off-canvas menu slide over menu. I found a great example for one but it uses SCSS, is it possible to create the same exact one using CSS instead?

[Codepen demo here:](http://codepen.io/pongstr/pen/EiAfI)

```
<div data-off-canvas="true">
<div class="off-canvas-menu">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="off-body" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container-inner">
    <div class="container-content">

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="off-canvas" data-target="#off-body">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <h1 class="page-header">
        <i class="glyphicon"></i> Simple Off-Canvas 
      </h1>


[data-off-canvas="true"],
.container-fluid,
.container-inner,
.container-info {
 height: 100%;
}

.container-inner {
 display: table;
 width: 90%;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
}

.container-content {
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}

.page-header {
 font-family: "Bitter";
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 64px;
 letter-spacing: -1px;
 border-bottom: 0 none;
 text-shadow: 0 2px 8px darken(#05bb0e, 10%);
}

p.lead {
 font-weight: 300;
}

*:focus { outline: 0 none !important; }

[data-off-canvas="true"] {
 height: 100%;

 &.active {
  overflow-x: hidden;
 }
}

.col-xs-12 > .btn {
 margin-top: 15px;
 padding-left: 8px;
 padding-right: 8px;
}

.icon-bar {
 display: block;
 clear: both;
 width: 23px;
 height: 4px;
 margin-top: 2px;
 margin-bottom: 2px;
 background-color: #fff;
}

.off-canvas-menu {
 @include transition(left 155ms ease-out);
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 left: -250px;
 width: 250px;
 height: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
 box-shadow: -1px 0 1px 0 #313131 inset;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 background-color: #191919;

 &.active {
  @include transition(left 155ms ease);
  left: 0;
 }
}

.off-canvas-target {
 @include transition(transform 150ms ease);
 @include translate(0, 0);

&.active {
 @include transition(transform 150ms ease);
 @include translate(250px, 0);
 }
}

+function ($) { 'use strict'; 

var OffCanvas = function (element, options) {
this.element = (element) ? element : '[data-toggle="off-canvas"]';
this.options = (options) ? options : this.defaults;

return this;
};

OffCanvas.defaults = {};

OffCanvas.prototype.engage = function () {
var $target = $($(this.element).data('target'));

$target.addClass('off-canvas-target');

$(this.element).on('click', function (event) {
  var offCanvas    = '[data-off-canvas=true]',
      slideTarget  = $(this).data('target'),
      slideMenubar = '.off-canvas-menu';

  event.preventDefault();

  $(offCanvas).toggleClass('active');
  $(slideTarget).toggleClass('active');
  $(slideMenubar).toggleClass('active');

 });
};
```

Comment: To answer the question of "can it be done": Yes, it *can* be done with just JavaScript and CSS. Sass just adds some features from JavaScript into a CSS-esque environment for people who want more powerful control while creating styles. In fact, it can be done in [pure CSS alone](http://www.sitepoint.com/pure-css-off-screen-navigation-menu/) without any JavaScript whatsoever, though the features necessary for that aren't available in IE8, if legacy browser support is a concern for you.

Comment: scss compiles into css, so i fail to see where your issue is? Take the compiled CSS and use that instead?

Comment: I was able to view the generated CSS using Chrome Devtools, if you just looking for a way to poach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS portion in the codepen has a "view compiled" button, and that translates SCSS to CSS.

[image]